# Reset Password Link in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I get this error htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\password\reset.blade.php)"

This is my reset blade view

```
enter code here
```

```
                {!! Form::open(['url'=> 'password/reset', 'method'=>"POST"]) !!}
                   {{ Form::label('email','Email Address:')}}
                   {{ Form::email('email',$email,['class' => 'form-control'])}}

                   {{ Form::hidden('token',$token)}}

                   {{ Form::label('password','New password:')}}
                   {{ Form::email('password',['class' => 'form-control'])}}

                   {{ Form::label('password_confirmation','Confirm New password:')}}
                   {{ Form::email('password_confirmation',['class' => 'form-control'])}}





                   <br>

                   {{ Form::submit('Reset password',['class' => 'btn btn-primary  btn-block'])}}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
                <br>
            </div>
```

this is my method

```
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    return view('password.reset')->with(
        ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
    );
}
```

Comment: Please add more information, what code have you changed (controller), and the view in question

Comment: Can you please paste your HTML? you probably made mistake in your blade template for reset link.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong syntax for fields. Try this:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=> 'password/reset', 'method'=>"POST"]) !!} 
{!! Form::label('email','Email Address:') !!}
{!! Form::email('email',$email,['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
{!! Form::hidden('token',$token)!!}
{!! Form::label('password','New password:')!!}
{!! Form::email('password',['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
{!! Form::label('password_confirmation','Confirm New password:')!!}
{!! Form::email('password_confirmation',['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
<br>
{!! Form::submit('Reset password',['class' => 'btn btn-primary  btn-block'])!!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

replace all your `{{` with `{!!` and `}}` with `!!}`. While creating form fields you can't use `{{ }}`